# ORACLE Application Development Framework

Tags: oracle, mysql-workbench

Hello I am trying to build an application using Oracle ADF. 
I have designed my database using Oracle Workbench have all the tables in the database already linked.( be it one to many or one to one mapping with the primary and foreignm keys.) i hope to include triggers too.

My problem is when i do all these links in workbench.
Will it automatically link the tables up using Association when i I load the tables as entities.

Will it also create views and view links too for me.

Or i should just create the tables in the database and do the associations and links in jdeveloper instead when i start working on the UI of my project.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `New - Business Tier - ADF Business Components - Business Components from Tables` and go through the wizard pointint your tables in the database, JDeveloper should create Entities, link them with Associations, also create View Objects and link them with View Links based on your tables' foreign keys.
Triggers won't be reflected in the application.